# After click on button show in the *div* the text as heading 1 <h1>, second click <h2> etc. After 6, is next text (7th) as <h1> again

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, counter, heading

I want to make a website with text box, button using switch -case and div with id 'divResult'. If you click on button it shows  text from text box as heading 1 `<h1>`, after second click as `<h2>` etc. After 6, is next text (7th) as `<h1>` again. It works correct only last step (text in h1-h6) doesn't work.

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>7-3</title>
  <script >
    
var index = 1;
var countClicks = 0;

window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('btnKnop').onclick = function () {

    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = 'div' + index++;
    
    var node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);
    
    newElement.appendChild(newNode);

    
    console.log(newElement);
    document.getElementById('divResult').appendChild(newElement);


  countClicks++;
  switch (countClicks) {
    case 1: {
      console.log('heading text 1');
      break;
    }
    case 2:{
      console.log('heading text 2');
      break;
    }
    case 3:{
      console.log('head text 3');
      break;
    }
    case 4:{
      console.log('heading text 4');
      break;
    }
    case 5:{
      console.log('heading text 5');
      break;
    }
    case 6:{
      console.log('heading text 6');
      countClicks = 0;
      break;
      }
    }
       
  };
};  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtElement">
  <button id="btnKnop">Add</button>
  <div id="divResult"></div>
  

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: works just fine for me. You aren't adding <h1></h1>, <h2></h2>, ... elements though. But the divs are added (counting up from 1, 2, 3, ... and going up forever) as divs. You could always change your .createElement() syntaxes to have h1, h2, h3, ... in them. That is, if you want them to be h1, h2, ... and not <div id="div1">, <div id="div2">, ...

Comment: yes, You are right . But i don`t know exactly how to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using your HTML, and little JS, you don't need a switch statement for that

```js
var txtInput = document.querySelector("#txtElement"),
  resultElement = document.querySelector("#divResult"),
  ind = 0;

document.querySelector("#btnKnop").onclick = function() {
  ind = ind++ === 6 ? 1 : ind;
  resultElement.innerHTML += `<h${ind}>${txtInput.value}</h${ind}>`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop">Add</button>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Since you need to use a switch statement for your execise it can be like this:

```js
var txtInput = document.querySelector("#txtElement"),
  resultElement = document.querySelector("#divResult"),
  countClicks = 1;

document.querySelector("#btnKnop").onclick = function() {
  var h = "";
  switch(countClicks++) {
    case 1: h = "h1"; break;
    case 2: h = "h2"; break;
    case 3: h = "h3"; break;
    case 4: h = "h4"; break;
    case 5: h = "h5"; break;
    case 6: h = "h6"; countClicks = 1; 
  }
  resultElement.innerHTML += `<${h}>${txtInput.value}</${h}>`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtElement">
<button id="btnKnop">Add</button>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But i've got a condition to make it with switch statement. And i have to do it on that way, what i wrote.

Comment: Pls make it clear, what do you want to do?, do you want to add divs or headers?, or even headers inside divs?!

Comment: Oh , sorry ...  add headers ... so if you type some text in text box, after first click on button is text in h1, after second click on button is h2 ... till h6 ...on 7th click is h1 again.

Comment: Well I already made you a code snippet that does exactly that, typing a text then add it as `h1` element, press it again add another text as `h2` element and so on untill `h6` then after comes `h1` ones again, try it!

Comment: You are right !!! ..  But, this is an exercise from my course javascript/jquery and there are couple of conditions. like switch, case , divResult, etc.  That why it has to look like my script on the top. I cannot use your method :-( . And that symbol $ is in jquery , we will have it later, so i can't use it in this case ...

Comment: Can you share the exercise ?

Comment: yes, but i can make only picture of it or translate it to english.  But almost everything from  the exercise i already wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to see it in plain English if you can, even if it's just a picture

Comment: Create a web page with a text box, a button and a div with id 'div-Result'. Then write a script that displays the text from the text box as header <h1> in the 'div' after clicking the button. The second time the button is clicked, the text is displayed in header <h2> etc. When header 6 is reached, the following text is inserted again as header 1.
Practice using the following code to learn how to count to six using a switch statement while clicking a button. Use a similar switch statement.

Comment: Yes, I see, but still is there a symbol $ ..  i can't use it. It is not allowed.

Comment: Ok I see, you are talking about `resultElement.innerHTML += \`<${h}>${txtInput.value}</${h}>\`;`, that's my friend called [**Template Strings**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and it's ES6 feature, you can write the old concatenating style if you want `resultElement.innerHTML += "<" + h + ">" + txtInput.value + "</" + h + ">"`